# Grub won't install with Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I've been trying to install Arch Linux while dual booting windows on my laptop but upon trying to install GRUB, it gives me this error.

```
Installing for i368-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible
grub-install: warning: GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blockists are UNRELIABLE and their use is disc ouraged...
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I ran a command to open up a menu to install arch linux,

```
pacman -S wget pacman-contrib
wget archfi.sf.net/archfi
sh archfi
```

I then used the menu to partition my disk to FAT32 for the EFI and then EX4, and mounted it using the menu.
I'm using a HP laptop that I have had for 4 years I believe.

EDIT: Something happened to the USB where I had to use a MBOK key, and now it gave me more options in the install menu, It says GRUB installed, currently testing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some details. We need to see the _exact_ command you ran, first of all. Next, we will need to know something about your system and what drive you are installing to.

Comment: @terdon Okay did that for you.

Comment: That is even more confusing. Where did you run those commands? On Windows? On [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)? What does "some stuff" mean? What exactly did you do to get this error? We really cannot help if you don't tell us what you did. Are you following the official Arch installation guide?

Comment: @terdon I am currently going off this guide, It is basically my first time installing Arch Linux, And first time asking a question so bare with me here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbXHU7W7Its

Comment: Please don't follow random youtube videos. Arch has probably [the best documentation in the Linux world](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide), use that. But, again, in order to help you, we need to know what you did and telling us you did "some stuff" isn't helpful. So, again, you say you "ran a command to open up a menu". Where did you run this? In Windows? How? Then you say you did "some stuff" and got an error message. OK, what stuff? What was the _exact_ command that gave you that error?

Comment: The stuff I did was partition my disks as FAT32 for the EFI and then EX4 for the system.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the information. What disks? What commands did you run? _What exact command produced the error you are asking about_?

Comment: I didn't go off a command, I went off the menu (as I showed how to get the menu with the pacman command).

Comment: Then _tell us that_! Edit your question and explain. Were there any options in the menu? Which one did you select? Where did you tell it to install grub? Which device? Do you have many? Is this a laptop? A desktop? You have told us nothing about your system.

Comment: Okay give me a minute to rewrite my question then.

Comment: I have adjusted a few things in my BIOS settings and it's giving me more options? Because before I couldn't select a few things but now it seems to be working, I will see if it will boot in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, After messing around in BIOS, I turned on secure boot and went to Ventoy and added the MBOK key, After that GRUB installed perfectly fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB has detected that your computer is either unable, or configured not, to boot in UEFI mode.  But your hard drive is partitioned with GPT.  Options include:

- Go into BIOS to enable UEFI boot or correct the issue that is preventing it.
- Switch from GPT to an MBR partition table.  This can be done with `gdisk`.
- Create an unformatted partition that is marked for use by GRUB.  The most commonly recommended size for this empty partition is 8MB.  The easiest way to prepare partitions is with a GParted Live ISO.

Comment: This is very unlikely if the OP is dual booting Windows. Most probably they gave the wrong device to grub but we can't know because they haven't told us what they did.

Comment: *What* is "very unlikely"?  The error message OP described is produced by `grub-install` when GRUB detects the state I've described.  Windows versions through to 11 can be booted in Legacy mode, although doing so with Windows 11 does require a workaround.  OP has written an answer that describes fixing the problem by changing BIOS settings that were preventing UEFI from working.

Comment: It is very unlikely that on a system with Windows installed, which I believe requires UEFI these days, they would have booted in non-EFI mode. Or, for that matter, that they would want to install grub on a different partition on a non-gpt drive and not the main one used for the existing EFI. It seems more likely that the OP gave the wrong value somewhere. Perhaps a partition instead of a device? Also, grub is absolutely fine with GPT partition tables, I am writing this from a machine booted via grub from a GPT drive.

Comment: Only Windows 11 "requires" UEFI, and it is capable of booting in Legacy mode with workarounds.  I did not state that GRUB would not work with GPT.  The error message does not indicate that the user has entered anything incorrectly.  That is the *exact* error message that is displayed when the user attempts to install on a block device.  A *different* error message ("unable to identify a filesystem") is displayed when the user attempts to install to a partition.

Comment: OK. Maybe I misunderstood but when you say "can't/configured not to boot UEFI" and "_but_ your drive is GPT" and then suggest changing to MBR instead, that comes across as saying that grub cannot work with GPT.

Comment: "GRUB has detected... unable... to boot in UEFI mode."  Changing from GPT to MBR is an *option* to solve the problem.  Doesn't mean it is the only or recommended way.  Another, which in my earlier drafts was mentioned *first*, is to create an unused partition that GRUB can use to store the boot loader.  Another, which OP discovered on his own, is to fix the condition that is preventing UEFI from working.